# "Could have" and "can have" in a sentence using the present tense

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, subjunctives

> It is ten o’clock. They could have arrived now.
>   It is ten o’clock. They can have arrived.

What is the meaning of the above sentences?

What meaning do "could have" and "can have" give to sentences using the present tense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really is a matter of idiom—what people actually **do** say—not grammatical or logical meaning.

In strict logic, all of these amount to the same thing, that it is possible that they are right now at their expected destination:

- They can have arrived (by) now.
- They could have arrived (by) now.
- They may have arrived (by) now.
- They might have arrived (by) now.

*Could* or *might* suggest somewhat more uncertainty than *can* or *may*. *Can* and *could* address their command of the physical ability or resources, while *may* and *might* address the probability.

But in fact, the past form in this case will usually point to an implied unreal or highly unlikely contingency; and people are unlikely to use *can* or *could* in these circumstances except to draw a contrast between possibility and expectation:

- They **might** have arrived now—if they had left on time.
- They **could** have arrived now—if they had had a strong tailwind.
- They **can** have arrived now—but I doubt they have.

So what you probably want is

- They **may** have arrived now—why don’t you call and see if they’ve landed?

Comment: I have never heard "can have arrived" in the US. I did a quick Google search and the examples seem to be European and not from recent times.

Comment: @user3169 I agree. I can conceive circumstances when it might be used, but they're pretty far-fetched.

Comment: I think this is the right answer - *they **can** have arrived by now* is idiomatically unlikely, but it's certainly not "incorrect" in any absolute sense. And even if I can't come up with one off the cuff, I'm quite prepared to believe there are contexts where it would be the *preferred* phrasing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oddly, however, *They **can't** have arrived yet* works just dandy.

Comment: Good point. So if you wanted to take issue with someone who'd just said that, it seems to me you could reasonably say *"I disagree. I think they **can** have arrived by now"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly. Which might arise once or twice in a lifetime, so ya gotta be ready with a snappy (but grammatical) response.